# Proof that infinity norm is a norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Tags: analysis, solution-verification, normed-spaces

I want to show that in the case where $p = \infty$ that $||x||_\infty = \max_{1 \leq i \leq n} |x_i|$ does define a norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$. There issue I have is the triangle inequality, I know that there are some very straightforward proofs such as $$|x_j+y_j|\le |x_j|+|y_j|\le\|x\|_\infty+\|y\|_\infty$$ which I understand having seen them, but what I had done was the following. If we have $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, then
$$
||x+y||_\infty= \max_{1\le i \le n} |x_i+y_i| \leq \max_{1\le i \le n} |x_i|+|y_i| = \max_{1\le i \le n} |x_i|+\max_{1\le i \le n}|y_i| = ||x||_\infty+||y||_\infty
$$
Is this wrong? All the other proofs seem to consider any index $j$ which are evidently less than the infinity norms, but this was what came to my head first and I want to know if my logic is wrong somewhere. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: You can't say that $\max |x_i| + |y_i| = \max |x_i| + \max |y_i|$. Try coming up with a counterexample for this.

Comment: Yeah just saw it thanks boss.